# Install Ubuntu with Win10 on different SSD

Tags: windows

I have Win10 installed on a m.2 SSD. I bought a new SATA ssd for ubuntu. Should I choose "Install alongside Win10" or "Erase and install Ubuntu" for the new SSD?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use **Manual partitioning**, since the other options will install Ubuntu on the m.2 SSD. Refer to [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

(This answer assumes you're using UEFI boot. It might be more complicated if you're using BIOS.)

Comment: Thank you! If I simply want to boot into Windows by default and boot into Ubuntu by press F12 and choose Ubuntu disk, do I need to create a EFI partition manually?

Comment: @Chao You mean you want to boot into Ubuntu using the firmware boot menu? If yes, you can use the existing EFI partition or create a new one on the SATA SSD - it depends on your needs. But you might want to ask a new question to clarify that. I'm hazy on the details.

Comment: Yes. During the manual partitioning, I think I need to create a EFI partition and choose the bootloader to be installed in it.